# Google Compute Engine VM stops after some time

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

We're encountering a very strange problem at my company. Since a month ago, we used to publish images with **Docker** on **Container Registry**, then deploy them to **Compute Engine** (which creates an instance of a VM) and it worked fine.

Since 2 weeks ago, when we depoy an image from Container Registry to Compute Engine, the VM starts and works fine for some time, but after some hours it stops forever. We currently have a paying plan, so I guess this is not a payment issue.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is it a **firewall** issue? All the logs from the VM seem fine.

Here are the last logs of the VM:

```
[ 7214.995439] google_accounts_daemon[465]: Adding user toto to group google-sudoers
[ 7449.139530] google_accounts_daemon[465]: Removing user toto from group google-sudoers
[226991.170566] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[226991.206891] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: 
[227024.855486] LoadPin: kernel-module pinning-excluded obj="/lib/modules/5.4.49+/kernel/fs/fat/fat.ko" pid=40981 cmdline="/sbin/modprobe -q -- fs-vfat"
[227024.880466] LoadPin: kernel-module pinning-excluded obj="/lib/modules/5.4.49+/kernel/fs/fat/vfat.ko" pid=40981 cmdline="/sbin/modprobe -q -- fs-vfat"
[227024.899845] LoadPin: kernel-module pinning-excluded obj="/lib/modules/5.4.49+/kernel/fs/nls/nls_cp437.ko" pid=40988 cmdline="/sbin/modprobe -q -- nls_cp437"
[227024.917675] LoadPin: kernel-module pinning-excluded obj="/lib/modules/5.4.49+/kernel/fs/nls/nls_iso8859-1.ko" pid=40990 cmdline="/sbin/modprobe -q -- nls_iso8859-1"
```

Comment: Is your VM preemptible?

Comment: What if any logs explaining why the Compute Engine stopped are logged?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no, it's specified Preemptible: Off

Comment: @Kolban I added the last logs from my machine, I don't understand why are users being removed? Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: have you made any changes before deploying this? I dont see any reason why the VM would terminate due to a user being added and removed from sudoers group unless thats the user you are using to deploy the vms and maybe they dont have the permission to do so

Answer (score 0):

According to the GCP docs [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#autorestart), you can set the option of automatically restarting the vm to true. So it will restart the instance after failing.

To enable:

$ gcloud compute instances set-scheduling [instance-name] --zone [instance-zone] --restart-on-failure